# How Islam allow or disallow new innovation and technology?

Tags: practical-islam, technology

Any our of our (Muslim) activities are referenced to Prophet's SAWW sunnah and Quran. I am curious to find out, **How Modern technology is supported or discouraged in Islam,** because it cannot be linked to prophet saww era directly.

This question came out in a discussion with my friend, whose main argument was that **Islam is changing with modern technologies, by allowing them to use**.

I argued by the comment that **Islam is the same, it tests and then approves/disapproves these technologies by comparing them to basic Islamic Principles.**

I could not find any support to my argument. I would like an appropriate answer with reference.

Comment: It matters if the new technology is good or bad for you.

Comment: Exactly @Armaan. What are the islamic procedures that figure out that it is good or bad?

Comment: If it goes against Quran and Sunnah, it is bad and if it doesn't, it would be allowed.

Comment: I suppose it is not simple as that, Does a Printer goes against Quran and Sunnah, because it was banned in Turkey, when firstly invented, look here: https://www.dailysabah.com/feature/2015/06/08/myths-and-reality-about-the-printing-press-in-the-ottoman-empire  Modern Technologies include a million things that does not go along or against Quran directly.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there is no set or defined rules to identify any newly introduced thing as Halal or Haram (which is not specifically mention in the Quran and Hadith). Otherwise, anyone can become Mufti and publish his own Fatwah.

Every Mufti judges on their own study, understanding, their effect in the society, cultural behaviors, long-run effects in the society, practical effects observed on the next generations. This is why we see different Fiqqah's in Islam. Otherwise, there were only one Fiqah.

This is same like, if you pass LLB Degree and you can become a lawyer. But you are not a Judge. You spend a time in practice then if you get appointed in Session Court then you become a Judge. But still, you are not final Judge to declare decision. Public can take or challance your decision to High Court and even to Supreme Court. Every Judge has different skill & experience level and angle of observation. Same applies to Islamic Mufti.

If you see, each Mufti/Scholar may have different educated opinion and recommendations on a matter.

A fatwā is an Islamic legal pronouncement, issued by an expert in religious law (mufti) where Islamic jurisprudence (fiqh), is unclear.

We might compare a fatwā to the legal ruling of a high court or the Supreme Court, depending on the authority of the mufti behind it. However, a fatwā is not binding as is the verdict of the secular courts; while correct and applicable to all members of the Muslim faith, the fatwā is optional for the individual to respect or not.

It is not allowed for anyone to give a Shari¿ah explanation (fatwā), except one

- who knows the Holy Qur’ān completely including what verses are abrogated and by which verses they were abrogated, and which verses resemble each other in the Qur’ān and whether a chapter was revealed in Makkah or Madina.
- He must know the entire corpus of the Hadith of the Prophet (s), both those which are authentic and those which are false. He must know the Arabic language of the time of the Prophet (s) with its grammar and eloquence as well as know the poetry of the Arabs.
- Additionally, he must know the culture of the various peoples who live in each different nation of the community. 
  *If a person has all such attributes combined in himself, he may speak on what is permitted (ħalāl) and what is forbidden (ħarām). Otherwise he has no right to issue a fatwā.*

It often happens that different Islamic clerics issue contradictory, or competing, fatwās. This divergence of opinion is not considered an issue in Islam; in fact, a well-known saying states that such differences among scholars are God’s mercy, for they allow for different conditions and temperaments among people.

Also, the luxurious cars fatwa reference is addressed to only clergy and clergy students as mentioned here: http://english.khamenei.ir/news/4633/It-is-haram-for-the-clergy-to-use-luxury-cars-Ayatollah-Khamenei

Here is another version of Fatwa and declared luxury life as Haram (*which you can follow or unfollow on some bases*): http://www.khilafah.com/is-it-forbidden-to-live-a-luxurious-life-in-islam/

Comment: I am very thankful for the time you spent on this spectacular answer, But i am expecting an answer with references, that would show that how Mufti's(sunni) and Mujahedeen(shia) sort out a technology Halal or Haram.
Recently Syed Ali Khamenei(Supreme leader of Iran) stated luxurious cars as Haram. I am interested to know, the stepwise procedure that leads technology permissible or non permissible, and please edit your answer with little less and to the point information, regards

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: Have updated my question by adding a conclusion at the end. Also, the luxurious cars fatwa reference is addressed to only clergy and clergy students. 
http://english.khamenei.ir/news/4633/It-is-haram-for-the-clergy-to-use-luxury-cars-Ayatollah-Khamenei

Here is another version of Fatwa and declared luxury life as Haram (_which you can follow or unfollow on some bases_): http://www.khilafah.com/is-it-forbidden-to-live-a-luxurious-life-in-islam/

Comment: +1 for remarkable conclusion, just try adding some reference to your conclusion as the answer lies with-in. I suppose an edit with only conclusion part as answer. Also try adding the references, you mentioned in comments, in you your post.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you please mind explaining "the fatwā is optional for the individual to respect or not." because i think fatwa must be followed by everyone.right!

Comment: can you give proof for "It is not allowed for anyone to give a Shari¿ah explanation (fatwā), except one who ..." part?

Comment: @qdinar, is it right or possible to accept arguments from a non-medical persons instead of a Doctor when we are discussing Medical or Health issues? Same way, it is not right that everyone start giving Fatwa's without having remarkable or recognizable Islamic studies. Will you accept my Fatwa right away? Ofcourse not! Let's conclude here in shortest statement.

Comment: @Seeker, sometime a Fatwa is bounded to a certain group, geography, time period. Also as mentioned, sometimes the person has a different understanding and experience level than others. So, if one Mufti is giving Fatwa and other is saying that it can be ignored so there is no big deal.
For example, in Pakistan, Islamic Nazriati Council gave Fatwa that a man should at least have 2 wife. Now people can follow it or may not follow. But this a great and lengthy debate what you have asked. So in simplest form I have tried to explain. Our self-study of Quran&Tafseer helps to understand and decide.

Comment: I am really thankful for the effort you have gone through and helping me out with this question, but i am gonna wait for someone else to support some of the points in you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Guys modern technology is permissible until and unless it does not violate the principles of Quran and Sunnah. However, for your seeking answer, it may be allowed by ijma that is a consensus of legal opinion of Islamic Jurist as a secondary source of Islamic law. Furthermore, if a new situation or case arise in Muslim community in modern world ijma, ijtihad and Masali Mursala (Extended Analogy) and other secondary sources of Islamic law can be used as an authentic source to permit new technology in Islam.

Answer (score -2):

Islam allow inovation and technology but in one case if the the technology follow islamic rules else islam can't allow those technology which is against islam because the first chemist is a muslim and the first doctor is a muslim

Comment: Do you have any evidences support your claims? See [answer].